# Сохранение значения таблицы в массив Javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите, пожалуйста! Есть двумерный массив, значения из него записываются в html таблицу. Таблицу можно редактировать в браузере и новые значения должны сохранятся. И при следующем открытии документа, показываются уже новые значения. 
Как реализовать сохранение на Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Прежде вам надо решить - это сохранение должно быть доступно только на устройстве пользователя, который редактирует(тогда вам надо смотреть в сторону [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)) или всем пользователям (в этом случае вам не обойтись без серверной части)